# Split output results into two horizontal sections of same table in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, html-table

I want to split the output of particular result in such a way, that it will be fit into browser width into two sections horizontally.
The number of rows I will get from service is dynamic. So it cannot be fixed.
Also I don't want to consider records to be consider half in one section, and have another section in another table hardcoded.
Is there any way which can be done through table properties, css or some other way.

For better way of what I meant, I am attaching screenshot what I have meant.
Currently I am working in angular js 1.1.
The result is not particularly expected in angular js. Any solution is fine.
Please find the sample output I'm expecting like this:

[image]

Let me know in case additional details are required.

Comment: what is your output like

Answer (score 0):

I think at this case it will be comfortable to create custom directive with input parameters: `items` - all input items and `size` - number of rows at left table.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      $scope.items.push({head1:i, head2:i, head3:i});
    $scope.size = 6;
}])
.directive('tables', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        size: '=',
        items: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.$watch('size', function(){
        $scope.tables = [
            $scope.items.slice(0, $scope.size),
            $scope.items.slice($scope.size, $scope.items.length)
        ];
      });
    },
    template: `
      <table ng-repeat='table in tables' style='float:left'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat='head in [1,2,3]'>Head {{head}}</th>            
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat='item in table'>
            <td ng-repeat='(key, value) in item'>{{value}}</td>            
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>`
  }
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>
         size: <input type='text' ng-model='size'/>
    </div>
    <tables items='items' size='size'/>
</div>
```